# pyspark check if HH:mm:ss is in a range

Tags: pyspark, timestamp, range

I have some data looks like this.

```
time
08:28:24
22:20:54 
12:59:38
21:46:07
```

I want to select the time that stand between 16:00:00 and 23:59:59, this is a closed range.

What should i do with it? ('Time' column type is string.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition can be simplified to checking if the hour part of your `time` column is between `16` and `23`.

You can get the hour by using [`pyspark.sql.functions.split`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) to tokenize the `time` column on the `:` character. Extract the token at index 0 to get the hour, and make the comparison using [`pyspark.sql.Column.between()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.between) (which is inclusive of the bounds).

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
df.where(split("time", ":")[0].between(16, 23)).show()
#+--------+
#|    time|
#+--------+
#|22:20:54|
#|21:46:07|
#+--------+
```

Note that even though `split` returns a string, there is an implicit conversion to `int` to do the `between` comparison.

---

Of course, this could be extended if you had more complicated filtering criteria that also involved looking at minutes or seconds:

```python
df.select(
    "*",
    split("time", ":")[0].cast("int").alias("hour"),
    split("time", ":")[1].cast("int").alias("minute"),
    split("time", ":")[2].cast("int").alias("second")
).show()
#+--------+----+------+------+
#|    time|hour|minute|second|
#+--------+----+------+------+
#|08:28:24|   8|    28|    24|
#|22:20:54|  22|    20|    54|
#|12:59:38|  12|    59|    38|
#|21:46:07|  21|    46|     7|
#+--------+----+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the column function [between](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.between) when you convert your column. See the example with comments below:

```
import datetime
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

#pyspark does not provide a type to hold time only values,
#therefore we have to work with the datetime format.
#When your string  only represents the time, pyspark will automatically add the current date.
#The filter expression we will use later for your range needs also the current date.
now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

l1 = [('08:28:24',)
    ,('22:20:54',)
    ,('12:59:38',)
    ,('21:46:07',)
    ,('16:00:00',)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(l1,['time'])
#Converting
df = df.withColumn('time', df.time.cast(T.TimestampType()))
#Applying your filter with the current date
df = df.filter(F.col("time").between(now + ' 16:00:00',now + ' 23:59:59'))

df.show()
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+ 
|               time|
+-------------------+
|2019-03-12 22:20:54| 
|2019-03-12 21:46:07| 
|2019-03-12 16:00:00| 
+-------------------+
```