# Is there anyway to see if time is in an interval?

Tags: python, apache-spark, time, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with pyspark and I have several dates with STRING TYPE, like:

```
DATE 
2019-03-01 18:04:42 
2019-02-01 18:34:44 
2019-04-01 19:04:43
```

I need to know if the records are between 7 and 19, it doesn't matter the day, 
is there a way to do it?

I would like to have something like

```
DATE                 |TIME 
2019-03-01 18:04:42  | day 
2019-02-01 18:34:44  | day
2019-04-01 19:04:43  | night
```

Comment: You could either [convert your strings to timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39088473/pyspark-dataframe-convert-unusual-string-format-to-timestamp) and use the [`hour`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.hour) function or process the string in a way similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55130068/pyspark-check-if-hhmmss-is-in-a-range).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_unixtime, unix_timestamp, when
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('2019-03-01 18:04:42',),('2019-02-01 18:34:44',),('2019-04-01 19:04:43',)],('DATE',))
df.show()
+-------------------+ 
|               DATE| 
+-------------------+ 
|2019-03-01 18:04:42| 
|2019-02-01 18:34:44| 
|2019-04-01 19:04:43| 
+-------------------+
```

Convert the `string` into `timestamp` using [`unix_timestamp`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp) function and once converted, you can extract the `hour` part using function [`from_unixtime`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime) by specifying pattern `'HH'`.

```
df = df.withColumn('hour', from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(df['date'], 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), 'HH'))
df.show()
+-------------------+----+ 
|               DATE|hour| 
+-------------------+----+ 
|2019-03-01 18:04:42|  18| 
|2019-02-01 18:34:44|  18| 
|2019-04-01 19:04:43|  19| 
+-------------------+----+
```

Finally just use [`when`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) function which is a pseudonym for `if-else` clause to get day/night.

```
df = df.withColumn('TIME',when(((col('hour') >= 7) & (col('hour')< 19)),'day').otherwise('night')).drop('hour')
df.show()
+-------------------+-----+ 
|               DATE| TIME| 
+-------------------+-----+ 
|2019-03-01 18:04:42|  day| 
|2019-02-01 18:34:44|  day| 
|2019-04-01 19:04:43|night| 
+-------------------+-----+
```